# Fluentd wildcard out_file with tag in file path

Tags: fluentd

I'm just getting started with fluentd, but I would like to be able to set up a single output match rule, like so:

```
<match myapp.**>
   type file
   path logs/
   time_slice_format %Y%m%dT%H
   time_slice_wait 5m
   time_format %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z
</match>
```

This works great, but I would like to find a way to further add the name of the tag into the output filename; is this possible?  For example, if I log with `myapp.debug` I would like it to write to `logs/myapp.debug20140918T12_0.log`, and if I log with `myapp.info` it would write to `logs/myapp.info20140918T12_0.log` etc

Is there a way to add the tag into the filename?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `fluent-plugin-forest` plugin.

https://github.com/tagomoris/fluent-plugin-forest